# ios/objective-c/xcode: tableview encroaches on toolbar

Tags: ios, uitableview, toolbar

In testing my app, I have observed behavior where for unknown reasons the tableview which is blue in my app arbitrarily covers the toolbar. It happen, as one example, after the app launches a map view.  When you close the map view, you do not see it from a modal controller.  However, you see it afterwards with all the tableview controllers that are tab items.

When this happens, you see blue, the color of the table view, and also the lines of the tableview superimposed on the toolbar, the icons of which, are still visible underneath.

The app uses storyboard and the tableviews are within regular view controllers.

Has anyone run across this before?

**Edit:**

The map view is launched with a button segue as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMap"]) {
  UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
        IDMapView *destViewController = (IDMapView * )navController.topViewController;
            destViewController.contact=_contact;
}}
```

The map view controller then launches the map with the following method in viewwillappear:

```
-(void) geoCodeIt {

    NSString* location = [self getBestAddress];
    NSLog(@"going to map this address:  %@",location);
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                                               initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                     MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(placemark.coordinate, 5000, 5000);
                     region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                     region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                     [self.mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
  }}];}
```

Comment: There's no way to provide you much help with so little info. Update your question with a lot more details about how things are setup.

Comment: Added image.  Toolbar is normally white.  Tableview is normally blue.  However, after launching another app such as maps from within mine and then returning to my app the above happens.

Comment: How did you set up your storyboard and constraint is unknown to us, if its programmatically made, you could atleast provide as a snap shot of your code where it is being practically drawn.

Comment: I have added the relevant methods as launching map view seems to cause the problem.

Comment: One thing that might give you better information is Xcode's View Debugging feature that lets you take a snapshot of the views being displayed and look at their attributes.

Comment: Is that under debug-view debugging.  When I clicked on this nothing happened.

Comment: So much for providing all the additional code requested...